# Use regex to identify 4 to 5 numbers that are (consecutive, i.e no whitespace or special characters included), without including preceding 0's

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am trying to use regular expressions to identify 4 to 5 digit numbers. The code below is working effectively in all cases unless there are consecutive 0's preceding a one, two or 3 digit number. I don't want '0054','0008',or '0009' to be a match, but i would want '10354' or '10032', or '9005', or '9000' to all be matches. Is there a good way to implement this using regular expressions? Here is my current code that works for most cases except when there are preceding 0's to a series of digits less than 4 or 5 characters in length.

```
import re

line = 'US Machine Operations | 0054'
match = re.search(r'\d{4,5}', line)
if match is None:
    print(0)
else:
    print(int(match[0]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!\d)[1-9]\d{3,4}(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XSzi9B/1).

**NOTE**: In Pandas `str.extract`, you must wrap the part you want to be returned with a *capturing group*, a pair of unescaped parentheses. So, you need to use

```
(?<!\d)([1-9]\d{3,4})(?!\d)
       ^            ^
```

Example:

```
df2['num_col'] = df2.Warehouse.str.extract(r'(?<!\d)([1-9]\d{3,4})(?!\d)', expand = False).astype(float)
```

Just because you can simple use a capturing group, you may use an equivalent regex:

```
(?:^|\D)([1-9]\d{3,4})(?!\d)
```

**Details**

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit immediately to the left
- or `(?:^|\D)` - start of string or non-digit char (a non-capturing group is used so that only 1 capturing group could be accommodated in the pattern and let `str.extract` only extract what needs extracting)
- `[1-9]` - a non-zero digit
- `\d{3,4}` - three or four digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit immediately to the right is allowed

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/S419Ol):

```
import re
s = "US Machine Operations | 0054 '0054','0008',or '0009' to be a match, but i would want '10354' or '10032', or '9005', or '9000'"
print(re.findall(r'(?<!\d)[1-9]\d{3,4}(?!\d)', s))
# => ['10354', '10032', '9005', '9000']
```

Comment: @Royale_w_cheese You need to use a capturing group with `str.extract`: `df2['num_col'] = df2.Department.str.extract(r'(?<!\d)([1-9]\d{3,4})(?!\d)', expand = False).astype(float)`

Comment: @Royale_w_cheese I am not quite sure it is related to the regex itself (as in the question), it is something related to Pandas and your data. If you need more help, you probably should either provide a reproducible example here, in the question, or ask a separate question if you are sure it is some unique issue.